# A pythonic method to find the item with most occurrences and its number of occurrences in a list in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have an array

```
arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
```

What would be the most efficient and "pythonic" way to find the item with the most occurrences and how many times it occurs in the list?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient and "pythonic" way to find the item with the most occurrences and how many times it occurs in the list?

Use [Collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to get a `dict` of each element with value as their occurrence and use [most_common](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) for finding the element having highest occurence. Try this:

```
import collections

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,3]
counts = collections.Counter(arr)

print("Counter:", counts)
# counts.most_common()   # Returns all unique items and their counts
print("Most Occurred:", counts.most_common(1)[0][0])  # Returns the highest occurring item
```

Outpus:

```
Counter: Counter({3: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
Most Occurred: 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When I run this, I get: `Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})`. How would I proceed with storing the number of occurrences of the mode,  which is 2,  in a variable.

Comment: I have updated as well.